# JUnit Testcase not executing properly

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to execute a simple testcase using JUnit, but the testcase always *passes* even in false condition. I am not able to figure out the mistake in my program below. It looks like somewhere there is a mistake with the Scanner class multiple inputs.

I would like to test with multiple inputs to the testcase such that the test case accepts different employee types.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class EmployeeIdentificationTest extends TestCase {
    String firstName, middleName,lastName;
       int age=0;

       String choice=null;

       // assigning the values
       protected void setUp(){
          do{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

           System.out.println("Enter  firstName  ");
           firstName= scanner.nextLine();
           System.out.println("Enter middleName");
           middleName= scanner.nextLine();
           System.out.println("Enter lastName");
           lastName= scanner.nextLine();
           System.out.println("Enter the age");
           int flag=0; 
           while(flag==0){
            try{
               age= scanner.nextInt();
               flag=1;
               }
               catch(Exception e){
               scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Wrong entry, please enter digits only:");
            }
          }

        System.out.println("Do you like to fetch more records press Yes or No");
       scanner.nextLine();   
       choice=scanner.nextLine();
       }while(choice.contains("Y")||choice.contains("y"));      
       }
       // test method 
       public void testEmployee(){
       String employeeType=EmployeeIdentification.getEmployeeType(firstName, middleName, powerTrain, age);
       if(employeeType.equals("Junior Developer")||employeeType.equals("Senior Developer")||employeeType.equals("System Analyst")||employeeType.equals("Manager")||employeeType.equals("Delivery Head"))
       assert(true);
       }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Valid points from Ldvg, I think what you mean to write is:

```
public void testEmployee(){
    String employeeType = EmployeeIdentification.getEmployeeType(firstName, middleName, powerTrain, age);
    if(employeeType.equals("Junior Developer")||
        employeeType.equals("Senior Developer")||
        employeeType.equals("System Analyst")||
        employeeType.equals("Manager")||
        employeeType.equals("Delivery Head")) {
        assert(true);
    } else {
        assert(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work but the assertTrue works fine. Now the multiple input test cases is not working. It works only if i give no

Comment: Try different assert options: [assert statement options](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html)

Comment: Problem: you are trying to get multiple inputs, but you are not using the proper data structure to hold these input. Suggestion: create a List<Employee> object to hole these inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
assert(true);
```

This line will always return true. The assert keyword will evaluate the expression given after it. You have to assert that the employeeType that the user selected is one of which you accept(i guess you keep them in a list).

A usecase for assert could look like this:

```
assert(a+b == c);
```

if you wish to verify that the result of a+b is equal to c.

Comment: From where do you call your test method testEmployee()?

Comment: Have you tried exactly this line:

    assert(emplooyeeType.equals("Junior Developer"));

Comment: Try adding the @Test tag above your method.

Comment: It executed fine now. but the multiple inputs is not working.

Comment: It only works for condition No but when i give yes its not checking the condition its taking input

Comment: Are you saying you are asked to enter name,middle,lastname, age, then when you get asked if you wanna input more "No" cancels the program as it should, but "yes" does not allow you to do the inputs again?

Comment: After entering all the values name, middle, lastname, age the testcase  does not execute.. when i enter No the testcase executes..when i give Yes again the inputs are prompted without assertion

Comment: Oh i see. This is due to your method "setUp()". a setUp method will always  be ran first when you have your class to extend TestCase. Running such a class will preform:

1. setUp() {...}

2. methods with @test from top to bottom

3. tearDown(){...}

So what im trying to say is that your test method wont run until the setUp is done, which is only when you have written "No" to exit the loop.

Comment: Just want to point out a fact that you didn't implement the fixture in the right way, you can either 1. extends TestCase and override its run() or runTest() or 2. don't extends TestCase class but using the @Test annotaion, in this case, don't use the setup()

Comment: It does not work in this way too. The problem is with the do while loop. It keeps executing at a whole. We need to find a way to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit checks for various asserts to pass/fail a test, so if you have

```
assert(true);
```

it will always pass.

```
assert(false);
```

it will allways fail.

use the conditions you need to test within assert. i.e.

```
assert(employeeType.equals("Junior Developer"));
```

Comment: still if i remove the assert(true), with only  employeeType.equals("Junior Developer"),  the test case passes even with wrong input

Comment: try assertTrue(employeeType.equals("Junior Developer"));